# QLineEdit dont want to save changes :(

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

stackoverflow!

It's my first question, I was just a reader before

I'm trying to make an app in python using PyQt5: I need to get data from DB into a table, every row has an EDIT button, when you push it, fields of the row become editable and you can change the data and the EDIT button changes to SAVE button. When you push it , data should be saved and be sent to database(I didn't made a "commit to DB" function yet) but its not saving and comes to previous amounts every time I click SAVE.

When I click EDIT button, it takes a cell text and than replace the widget in a cell by the same , but editable version(just change an option to EDITABLE = TRUE is not working), and it makes it for the whole row.

The save button should make the same, but it makes cells UNEDITABLE again...

tell me why it is so?

my function on SAVE button is

def ButtonSaveClicked(self):

```
s = self.sender()

roww = int((s.text().split())[1]) - 1

print('SAVE')

# replacing the existing active widgets by inactive with a same text

q = self.ui.tableWidget.item(roww, 0).text()
self.ui.btn_sell = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(q)
self.ui.btn_sell.setEnabled(False)
self.ui.tableWidget.setCellWidget(roww, 0, self.ui.btn_sell)


q = self.ui.tableWidget.item(roww, 1).text()
print(q)
self.ui.btn_sell = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(q)
self.ui.btn_sell.setEnabled(False)
self.ui.tableWidget.setCellWidget(roww, 1, self.ui.btn_sell)


q = self.ui.tableWidget.item(roww, 2).text()
print(q)
self.ui.btn_sell = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(q)
self.ui.btn_sell.setEnabled(False)

self.ui.tableWidget.setCellWidget(roww, 2, self.ui.btn_sell)




self.ui.btn_sell = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Edit " +str(roww+1))
self.ui.btn_sell.setEnabled(True)
self.ui.tableWidget.setCellWidget(roww, 3, self.ui.btn_sell)
self.ui.btn_sell.clicked.connect(self.ButtonEditClicked)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyEkk.png)

Comment: Can you share your code with a minimal reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Done , and i hope , in a right way

Answer (score 0):

I will attempt to answer your question, but I think you may also want to consider the following alternative:

You can set your table to have `Edit Triggers` instead of you needing to keep track of the state of a QPushButton and keep replacing items and copying data back and forth between them.

My suggestion would be to use the `QAbstractItemView::DoubleClicked` edit trigger and you can apply that to your `QTableWidget` like this:

```
self.tableWidget.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectItems)
self.tableWidget.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView::SingleSelection)
self.tableWidget.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::DoubleClicked)
```

If the user double clicks on a cell, that cell becomes editable.

`setSelectionBehavior()` lets you choose whether you want each cell, row or column to be selected when clicked.

`setSelectionMode()` determines whether one (cell,row,column) or many (cells,rows,columns) can be selected at once. I think in your case you want to select one cell at a time.

This way the user can double click the cells they wish to edit and then you can have a "Save" button at the bottom of the widget which saves all the changes.

I will try to reproduce your problem above, but I wanted to bring this functionality to your attention as it may save you a lot of headaches.